# Azure DevOpsのPipelinesで画像ファイルを使用する単体テストをする方法を知りたい

Tags: azure, テスト

### 概要

Azure DevOpsで管理している画像処理ライブラリの単体テストをAzure Pipelinesで自動化することを目指しています
ソースコードはReposで管理できておりますが、テストで使用する画像ファイルはどのように管理、運用すればよいかどうかを伺いたいです

### 詳細

画像処理ライブラリの単体テストをローカルで行う場合には、テストコードにローカルファイルのパスを指定して読みとりと処理を行っておりますが、これをAzure Pipeliesで実施しようとすると画像ファイルをどこに保存すればよいのかがわかりません
Azure DevOpsがLFSに対応しているとはいえ、処理によっては数十枚の画像ファイルを扱ったり、処理を追加するごとに画像の追加もあったりと、[公式ドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=azure-devops)にあるような「小さく更新がすくないファイルをcommitする」という方針にそぐわないことが気がかりです

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- リポジトリに入れてテストと一緒にバージョン管理したいのであればGit LFSを使うしかありません。
- そうはいってもHosted Agentは10GBまでという上限があるので、10GBを超える場合はself-hosted agentを使うことになります。
- self-hostedを使う場合はローカルマシン、もしくはAzure上のVMになるので、Azure Blobに置くとか、VMに保持するとかコストメリットで考えられます。

どこかのBlobをマウントしてhosted agentのローカルドライブとして使えれば一番いいんですけどね…。

Comment: 10GBの制限についてですが、これはReposでリポジトリのサイズが10GB以下であることが推奨されているものとは別の制限でしょうか?

Comment: はい、別の制限です。
[Hardware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#hardware)で書かれているように、agentはトータルで10GBしかディスクスペースの提供がありません。

Comment: 文中にある「This free space is consumed when your pipeline checks out source code」にはGit LFSで保存しているメディアデータが含まれるため、pipelinesで使用できるデータは10GBまでという認識でよろしいでしょうか?

Comment: はい、そうなります。ビルドやよそから取得したパッケージ、生成されるバイナリーも含んで10GBになるので、ゲームなどではちょっと厳しいですね。